# Sql Query to Get Nearest Value

Tags: sql-server-2008

Imagine I have the following table :

```
  --------------------------
  ID  -    NoOfOrders
  1   -       1
  2   -       3
  3   -       5
```

i need to get the nearest value to the parameter. e.g I send "4" as parameter i need ID 2 as result.

Comment: Why you are ignoring value 3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM table
WHERE NoOfOrders <= param
ORDER BY NoOfOrders DESC
LIMIT 1
```